# Insert code with JS just like echo in php

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get some code snippets from a PHP server to be "injected" in HTML. Basically when I open page.php I get some text like "_off".

The injection works with this code, however I can't use php in this html since it is local.

```
<img src="images/test
<?php
{ echo "_off"; }
?>
.jpg">
```

JavaScript seems to be the logical step. But if I just enter this at the position where I want the text of course it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $.get( "page.php", function( data ) { document.write(data); } ); </script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you can't use document.write like that. not after the page load has completed... since you're using jquery, just use standard dom injection techniques. e.g. `$('#someelement').load('page.php')`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$('#someElement').html(data)` or `$('#someElement').text(data)` if you want to write the data to a specific place on the page. You should avoid using `document.write`

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/yd9mx4d3/

Comment: Thanks, however like this it is not possible to add a string to a file name or is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow, but you don't have to set the text or html, you can also set a property `$('#someImage').prop('src', data);` or you could append to an existing property as well